# Bash: using cat within for loop

Tags: bash, cat

The following cat command seems to work fine outside the for loop but when I place it inside of it gives a syntax error:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 do
  cat file_$i | grep "random text" | cut -d':' -f2 > temp_$i
done
```

Could someone explain to me the correct way to write this? Thank you

Comment: What's the error it gives?  Also, grep can take a file as an argument so you don't have to cat a file and pipe it to it.

Comment: "Syntax error near unexpected token 'cat' "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `for` loop should have a semicolon:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do
```

Comment: Or put `do` on the next line.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to put `1 2 3 4 5` to loop through.

You can use [bash brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html). `{1..5}`

```
for i in {1..5}; do 
##
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer put "do" in the next line, this way helps me to don't remember use semicolons:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
  cat file_$i | grep "random text" | cut -d':' -f2 > temp_$i
done
```

Answer (score 1):

In bash, the **'end of the line' is implicitly considered as end of commands/statements** by bash compiler.

Example:

```
echo "Hello"
exit
#No need of semi-colons here as it is implicit that the end of the line is the completion of the statement
```

But when you want to add two statements/commands on the same line, you need to **separate them by semi-colon (;) explicitly**.

Example:

```
   echo "hello"; exit
#here semi-colon implies that the echo statement ends at the semi-colon and from there on to the end of the line is a new statement.
```

With respect to "for statement", the syntax goes as:

```
for variable in (value-set)
do
 ----statements----
done
```

So, either you put the `for`, `do` , `statements` and `done` in new line or separate them by semi-colons.